# How to split string values in lua. Error

Tags: string, csv, lua, split

So I'm trying to split just a string I've read in through a csv file. The string contains several values such as first_name, last_name, email_address, etc...  I want to use the split function to assign all those values to my own specific variables. So far this is what I have:

```
first_name, last_name, email_address, street_address, city, state = split(line, ",")
person_record = {first_name, last_name, email_address, street_address, city, state}
```

I'm getting an error in  lua saying  "Attempt to call global 'split' (a nil value)

I've googled with no success on the error message. Do I possibly have to include a library to use the split function????

Or am I just using the split function wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe that Lua has a `split` function as you're trying to use it.  [This page](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin) seems to be a thorough summary of how to split (and join) strings in Lua.

Comment: Thats the site where I learned you could split in lua. My problem is that I get an error when trying to split this way. I just want to know if I'm doing some syntactically wrong or...?

Comment: Have you read through that document?  There is no `split` function.  You have to write one.  Several implementations are provided on that page.  The opening paragraph (the stuff before "Joining list of strings") is just a description of the target operations, not a function reference.

Comment: derp. I guess I just though the bottom part was an example of one someone had made and there was a built in one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this python-like split implementation I wrote.

Arguments:

- s -- the string you want to be splitted
- pattern -- it's the delimiter (a char or a string)
- maxsplit -- at most this splits will be perfomed

Returns a table containing the splits.

Examples:

split('potato', 't') --> {'po', 'a', 'o'}

split('potato', 't', 1) --> {'po', 'ato'}

split('potato', 'ta') --> {'po', 'to'}

split('potato', 'foo') --> {'potato'}

```
split = function(s, pattern, maxsplit)
  local pattern = pattern or ' '
  local maxsplit = maxsplit or -1
  local s = s
  local t = {}
  local patsz = #pattern
  while maxsplit ~= 0 do
    local curpos = 1
    local found = string.find(s, pattern)
    if found ~= nil then
      table.insert(t, string.sub(s, curpos, found - 1))
      curpos = found + patsz
      s = string.sub(s, curpos)
    else
      table.insert(t, string.sub(s, curpos))
      break
    end
    maxsplit = maxsplit - 1
    if maxsplit == 0 then
      table.insert(t, string.sub(s, curpos - patsz - 1))
    end
  end
  return t
end
```

I hope it helps -^.^- Bye

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `split` function from the `pl.stringx` package:

Install the `penlight` package:

```
luarocks install penlight
```

Then in the program, you can use the package as shown here:

```
local split = require("pl.stringx").split
local paths = split("/a/b/feature-name/d", "/") 
-- output: {,a,b,feature-name,d}
local feature = paths[4] 
-- output: feature-name
```